# Exception while running Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have tomcat  server on windows 8 ,And I start tomcat through console i.e. using startup.bat. I got this exception.
I deleted work directory and stared again, It does not worked.

Uncaught error in scheduled job runner

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bitronix/tm/BitronixTransaction
at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.createTransaction(BitronixTran
sactionManager.java:448) ~[btm-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.begin(BitronixTransactionManag
er.java:158) ~[btm-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.moqui.impl.context.TransactionFacadeImpl.begin(TransactionFacadeI
mpl.groovy:336) ~[moqui-framework-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
at org.moqui.impl.service.ScheduledJobRunner.run(ScheduledJobRunner.groo
vy:109) [moqui-framework-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [
  ?:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_
     151]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
   access$301(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
   run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:
  1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?
  :1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoa
    der.java:1722) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoa
    der.java:1573) ~[?:?]
 ... 11 more
 Exception in thread "elasticsearch[MoquiLocal][management][T#5]" java.lang.NoCla
     ssDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/cluster/InternalClusterInfoService$1
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService.refresh(Internal
  ClusterInfoService.java:292)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService.maybeRefresh(Int
   ernalClusterInfoService.java:277)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService.access$500(Inter
   nalClusterInfoService.java:67)
   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService$SubmitRescheduli
   ngClusterInfoUpdatedJob.lambda$run$0(InternalClusterInfoService.java:224)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreserv
    ingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hint: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bitronix/tm/BitronixTransaction`

Comment: Can you please submit code how are you building artifact? i.e. pom.xml or gradle file?

Comment: I just deployed my war file(framework) in webapp directory...

Comment: @selvakumar I understand, but how are you building this war file? The problem might be that you didn't put this particular dependency in the war or just built war without dependencies without specifying additional classpath for tomcat